# Setting up data to compare several RMSE values - getting column name error

Tags: r, regression, r-caret

I'm trying to run a series of regressions and models on data. The following code is from a lecture and is giving me an error when I try to run it myself:

```
library(caret)
data(tecator)
fat = endpoints[,2]
PCA = prcomp(absorp)
scree = PCA$sd^2/sum(PCA$sd) * 100

set.seed(10)
lm_model = train(absorp, fat, method = "lm", preProcess = c("center", "scale"), trControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", repeats = 5))
lm_model
```

The error I get is `Error: Please use column names for x`

I'm trying to compare the RMSE of several different tests and compare them.

The lecture also runs the following codes which all give me the same error:

```
pls_model <- train(absorp, fat, method = "pls", tuneLength = 40, preProcess = c("center", "scale"), trControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv"), repeats = 5)

ridgeGrid = data.frame(.lambda = seq(0,1,length = 20))
set.seed(10)
ridge_model = train(absorp, fat, method = "ridge", tuneGrid = ridgeGrid, preProcess = c("center", "scale"), trControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", repeats = 5))

enetGrid = expand.grid(.lamdba = seq(0,1, length = 20), .fraction = seq(0.05, 1.0, length = 20))
set.seed(10)
enet_model = train(absorp, fat, method = "enet", tuneGrid = enetGrid, preProcess = c("center", "scale"), trControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", repeats = 5))
```

I'm lost as to why these won't work for me, but work for my professor. Is my data in the wrong format? These are his examples.

Comment: try doing `absorp <- as.data.frame(absorp)` then running the code. This works for me

Comment: you need to provide column names to ```absorp```. Either do ```absorp = data.frame(absorp)``` or ```colnames(absorp) = paste0("col",1:ncol(absorp))```